# How to resolve single-name (no dot) domain names with upstream DNS server?

Tags: networking, server, dns, dnsmasq, resolv.conf

I am using dnsmasq as the DNS repeater on my network, and it has the ability to answer domain name queries for entries in that machine's hosts file.  This gives me a convenient way to propagate a hosts file to all computers on the local network.  However Ubuntu machines on my local network refuse to pass on single-name (no dot) domain name queries to the DNS server.  Ubuntu machines try and resolve no-dot names locally only.

For example, I have a machine, **tusker** set to, say, 192.168.42.12.  In Windows, "`ping tusker`" resolves correctly to 192.168.42.12.  In Ubuntu, however, "`ping tusker`" results in "temporary failure in name resolution".  It doesn't seem to be passing on single-name domain name queries to the DNS server.  It sees there are no entries in its local hosts and stops there.

What do I need to do to get the DNS resolver in Ubuntu to pass up single-name domain queries?  I have tried "`options ndots:0`" in resolv.conf to no effect.

Comment: Does .local work? For example, I ping, SSH, or VNC into `kgiii-desktop.local` where the `kgiii-desktop` is the computer's name.

Comment: @KGIII No - in this case dnsmasq is getting the name, but it doesn't recognize it from its internal list.